# Unzip a file zipped in Unix using 7zip

Tags: excel, unix, compression, gzip, 7zip

My target is to send a file created by Unix process to myself as an excel file. So I have used the below commands to achieve it.

```
tr -d '\t' < PROGRAM_CREATED_FILE | sed -e 's/\\//g' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=">"; OFS="\t"} '{$1=$1}1' > file.xls
gzip -9 file.xls
echo "test mail" | sendxchange -a "file.xls.gz" -s "Report" my_mail_id
```

After receiving the file on my mail box, I save it in Windows machine. I try to extract the archive using 7zip. It attempts to extract and says **Data error in file.xls. File is broken**

Need help on this.

Thanks

Comment: What is `sendxchange` and where's it from?

Comment: sendexchange is tool to send mails from Unix server. I am just using that to send that compressed file Windows machine. I tried even FTP. The error is same

Comment: The gzipped file is binary, not ASCII. So you probably need to `uuencode` or base64 encode before attaching to the mail. And if transferring via FTP, you need to set BINARY mode before doing the `PUT`.

Comment: Please check the file you receive is **exactly** the same as the file you sent (md5sum?)

Comment: Thanks guys.. I was trying to FTP in ascii and it was failing. When I tried with binary, it worked. I am looking at `uuencode` right now @MarkSetchell Do help me by giving an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compressed file is binary rather than the ASCII that Mail expects to send. You can either `uuencode` it or `base64-encode` it prior to sending, like this:

```
gzip -9 < file.xls | uuencode -m file.xls.gz > file.xls.gz
... sendxchange -a "file.xls.gz" ...
```

Using the `-m` above gives `base64` encoding, and leaving it out results in `uuencoding`.

At the Windows end, you would need to decode the file again - for which you can use Microsoft's `certutil` tool (if you used base64 encoding), or the Unix utilities from SourceForge.

When transferring via FTP, be sure to set `BIN` mode first, else you may transfer in `ASCII` mode which is bad for binary files since it converts certain line-ending characters to the stupid Windows CR/LF combination and that may appear in your binary file an get converted - which is not what you want.

Comment: I am using 7zip to extract the archive. Below are the commands that I am using

`gzip -9 file.xls; uuencode file.xls.gz file.xls.gz | sendexchange -s "Subject" my_mail_id`

But I am unable to add any contents in the mail. If I use the commands you gave, **file.xls.gz** will be accessible in Windows right?